# command "mvn spring-boot:run" does not take changes at run in other modules than main module?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

i have a multi-modules maven, which is configured like that :

```
  sub-module maven : modul-main : contains the Main class and config folder with an application.properties file
  sub-module maven : modul-common : an another sub-module
```

if i update my code in modul-main, so the command

```
   mvn spring-boot:run
```

see my changes at run
but IF i update my code in modul-common, so the command

```
   mvn spring-boot:run
```

does not see my changes!

1. how explain that ? (what the command does in background ?) want to understand !
2. is there an option with this line command to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

That's how Maven works and this has nothing to do with Spring Boot. When you are in `module-main` and you run a command, it only impacts that module and Maven is not aware this module is part of a larger project that should be updated if necessary.

When you are in a particular module, dependencies are picked up via the local maven repository (not the individual `target/classes` locations for each module).

This is a significant difference compared to how Gradle works (running a command in a module is going to update sibling module automatically if needed).

Comment: ok @Stephan Nicoll, so only "mvn install" can fix it (by copying dependencies to .m2) ? or, is there any option in mvn spring;boot:run command ?

Comment: There is nothing specific in that command, that's just how Maven works as I've explained in my answer. Your repository should be up-to-date. When developing I recommend starting the app from your IDE and not the command line.